esp no_std rust persist data during deep sleeps
I currently try to port my esp application based on esp-idf (c) to rust esp no_std.
I have 1 problem I try to solve for quite some time and can't find a proper solution.
//! Stores measurements and sends once `x` measurements are collected

#![no_std]
#![no_main]

use core::time::Duration;

use esp_backtrace as _;
use esp_hal::prelude::ram;
use esp_hal::{entry, peripherals::Peripherals};
use esp_println::println;

mod sleep;
use self::sleep::enter_deep as enter_deep_sleep;

#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug)]
pub struct FloatMeasurement {
    /// The measured temperature in degree Celsius (°C).
    pub temperature: f32,
    /// The measured relative humidity in percent (%).
    pub humidity: f32,
}

use heapless::Vec;

#[ram(rtc_fast)]
static MEASUREMENTS: &'static Vec<FloatMeasurement, 10> = &Vec::new();

#[entry]
fn main() -> ! {
    let peripherals = Peripherals::take();

    loop {
        println!("{}", MEASUREMENTS.len());

        // not working below
        let _ = MEASUREMENTS.push(FloatMeasurement {
            temperature: 1.0,
            humidity: 2.0,
        });
        println!("{}", MEASUREMENTS.len());

        // if e.g. 10 then send and reset vec

        enter_deep_sleep(peripherals.LPWR, Duration::from_secs(4).into());
    }
}

Above is the extracted part of my application that doesn't work.
I found heapless Vector to be a good thing to use for what I want.
Then I found Once_cell as a solution, but after a few tries I couldn't make it work.
IF it is declared globally as static I can't get a mutable reference.
IF I would declare it as:
static MEASUREMENTS: &'static mut Vec<FloatMeasurement, 10> = &mut Vec::new();

I fails with
mutable references are not allowed in the final value of statics

I would be very happy for help how to properly have something like a globally accessable List of data, where I can write to and read from, there is only 1 thread accessing it for read/write, so actually no mutex needs to exist.
lazy_static also seems that it would do what I want, but it seems deprecated and the replacements i found where with only working with a std env.
---- EDIT ----
extracted to answer below.

"Then I found Once_cell as a solution, but after a few tries I couldn't make it work" -- What did you try? Also, does this environment have threads or interrupts/signals? That will affect what approaches are safe.

If you are 100% sure that no threads will ever exist and that execution cannot be preempted by signals/interrupts then you can use a static UnsafeCell initialized with a OnceLock. If you can't use a OnceLock then you will probably need an UnsafeCell<MaybeUninit> which you should initialize first thing in main().

in c it was:
static RTC_DATA_ATTR measurement measurements_buffer[20];
as a global variable and i can access that (write, read).
my problem is probably, that I currently don't understand how rust handles that access to the variable.

If you can use a local instead that would probably be preferred. If not then you will likely need static MEASUREMENTS: UnsafeCell<MaybeUninit<Vec<FloatMeasurement, 10>>> = UnsafeCell::new(MaybeUninit::new());. Then in main() you need to initialize it, and then after you can assume it's initialized.

thank you for your suggestion,
but OnceLock and MaybeUninit seem to be only available in std.
when I try it like this:
#[ram(rtc_fast)]
static mut MEASUREMENTS: OnceCell<Vec<FloatMeasurement, 10>> = OnceCell::with_value(Vec::new());
then it seems to work until the esp wakes up from deep sleep.
I can access it and iter/push... all without problem.
after it continues after it wakes:
unsafe precondition(s) violated: slice::from_raw_parts requires the pointer to be aligned and non-null, and the total size of the slice not to exceed isize::MAX
or it displays some random values/data.

I guess that only the.. UnsafeCell stores the pointer?? in RTC memory and the Vec is somewhere in ram that is not persisted during deep sleep. :/
i tried to adapt from this:
https://github.com/claudiomattera/esp32c3-embassy/blob/master/esp32c3-embassy/src/main.rs#L157

@Jürgen please don't post code in comments. Instead you can [edit] your question to include the code so that it will be properly formatted.

MaybeUninit is in core, so it's available for no_std.

thank you,
I believe there is a problem in my setup of the esp dev environment, as copy pasting the example from esp_hal doesn't work and running the code from the esp_hal repo works.
I might have to start fresh and see if it works.
I will further investigate to get something working and update my question with a working code.

I did not use once_cell, or anything other, because I keep it minimal.
Beware if threads or some other concurrent access to that data struct is needed, then some sort of locking is needed.
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

use core::time::Duration;

use esp_backtrace as _;
use esp_hal::prelude::ram;
use esp_hal::{
    clock::ClockControl,
    delay::Delay,
    entry,
    peripherals::Peripherals,
    prelude::*,
    rtc_cntl::sleep::{RtcSleepConfig, TimerWakeupSource},
    system::SystemControl,
};
use esp_println::println;
use esp_hal::rtc_cntl::Rtc;

#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug)]
pub struct FloatMeasurement {
    /// The measurred temperature in degree Celsius (°C).
    pub temperature: f32,
    /// The measured relative humidity in percent (%).
    pub humidity: f32,
}

use heapless::Vec;

#[ram(rtc_fast)]
static mut MEASUREMENTS: Vec<FloatMeasurement, 10> = Vec::<FloatMeasurement, 10>::new();

#[entry]
fn main() -> ! {
    let peripherals = Peripherals::take();
    let mut cfg = RtcSleepConfig::deep();
    cfg.set_rtc_fastmem_pd_en(false);
    let wakeup_source = TimerWakeupSource::new(Duration::from_secs(2));
    let mut rtc = Rtc::new(peripherals.LPWR);
    rtc.rwdt.enable();
    unsafe {
        // safe here because only 1 thread exists and we can be sure only we access it.
        println!("length {}", MEASUREMENTS.len());
        let _ = MEASUREMENTS.push(FloatMeasurement {
            temperature: 1.0,
            humidity: 2.0,
        });
        for x in MEASUREMENTS.iter() {
            println!("{}", x.humidity);
        }
        println!("--------------");
    }
    let system = SystemControl::new(peripherals.SYSTEM);
    let clocks = ClockControl::boot_defaults(system.clock_control).freeze();
    let delay = Delay::new(&clocks);
    delay.delay(500.millis());
    rtc.sleep(&cfg, &[&wakeup_source]);
    loop {}
}

this code works perfectly.. during trying to get it working, i overcomplicated the problem :) in real, the RTC memory was turned off, when going to deep_sleep.. so the solution was to.. keep it on (see snippet below)
`cfg.set_rtc_fastmem_pd_en(false);`

I got the hint from esp-rs team. https://github.com/esp-rs/esp-hal/issues/2516

( extracted from the edited question, question edited back.)

